# How to diagnose slow Entity Framework stored procedure call?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Problem: I'm calling a stored procedure through EF Core. When I run the stored procedure directly (via 'debug procedure'), it runs quickly, but it runs **VERY** slowly when called by EF's `FromSqlRaw`. So the problem appears to be when converting the returned data-table to a list of objects.

Setup:

1. Simple application with a list of blog posts. The stored procedure gets a hierarchical list of posts and associated users from a TPH table of posts, plus a table of users.

```cs
// Code is simplified, actually 8 parameters
SqlParameter depth_p = new SqlParameter("@depth", depth);
SqlParameter authorizedUserID_p = new SqlParameter("@authorizedUserID", authorizedUser.ID);
            
IQueryable<PostUser> query = postContext.PostUsers
            .FromSqlRaw("Post.USP_ReadDebate @depth, @authorizedUserID", 
            parameters: new[] { depth_p, authorizedUserID_p });
            
List<PostUser> postUsers = query.ToList(); // This hangs.
```

2. 26 columns are returned and converted by EF into the `PostUser` class.
3. `PostUser` holds 26 "ordinary" properties. No navigation properties, custom classes or any getters or setters that do any work.

```cs
public class PostUser
{
    // Post fields
    public Int32? ID { get; set; } // Primary Key
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public Guid OwnerID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }  // nullable
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeCreated { get; set; }
    public bool User_IsBanned { get; set; } = false;
    // some others...

    public PostUser() { }
}
```

4. Note: the stored procedure is very complex. It calls another stored procedure which fills a `@spid` table, then inserts the contents of that `@SPID` table into a table variable and returns that.
   But again when debugged directly it returns quickly, so I think the problem is when EF Core is converting the returned data to the `PostUser` object.
5. Bottom Line: is there any way to get visibility into what EF Core is doing on the conversion to `PostUser` to find the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `AsNoTracking()`?

Comment: I hadn't, upvoted b/c that's a good idea in this case no matter what.
However after adding that it didn't make a noticeable difference.

Comment: It was just idea, because EF will try to track entities. I would suggest to log which query will be generated by EF and try to run it without EF.

Comment: Thanks. The query is just calling the sproc so there is no EF query. Running the sproc w/o EF is fast ( 0.5 sec), with EF is over 8 minutes. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this?

Comment: @nonesuch No, I eventually broke down the process into two steps to get around the single EF procedure. Not ideal.